# Remote_table in spree 0.70.7 controller: #<TypeError: Zip is not a module>

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree

I'm include gem 'remote_table' in my Gemfile (Rails 3.1.12)
In spree admin i'd create new controller:

```
class Admin::XlsPriceLoadsController < Admin::BaseController
  def upload
    source_xls = RemoteTable.new(filename)
    source_xls.each do |row|
      ....
    end
  end
end
```

#### but when this action fired, i'm see the next:

```
  TypeError (Zip is not a module):

  app/controllers/admin/xls_price_loads_controller.rb:26:in `upload'

  ...
```

when i'm explore the source_xls object, a `frozen?` property of them is true.

So, can any soul write me, why the parsed object is frozed?
And, if i run this code

```
source_xls = RemoteTable.new(filename)
source_xls.each do |row|
  ....
end
```

from lib/tasks as rake task - all work fine!

Thanks for all advice!

Answer (score 0):

Whereabouts does the `filename` method/attribute come from? Is that something from spree? What value does it have at the point `#upload` is called?

Regarding

`app/controllers/admin/xls_price_loads_controller.rb:26:in`upload'`

What's on line 26?